# Какую базу данных выбрать? Или SQL + NoSQL ?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, php, nosql, sql

Разрабатываю сайты и приложения на php, и часто есть необходимость к одной ячейке прикрутить не фиксированный набор свойств (колонок), а произвольный, или какую-то хитрую древовидную структуру. Последние несколько лет работал с MySQL и сильно к ней привык, но сейчас она не удовлетворяет моим потребностям; можно конечно класть в таблицу JSON и каждый раз делать его encode|decode, но это же не выход! Поэтму смотрю в сторону NoSQL, присматриваюсь к MongoDB. Последняя опять же имеет иную, непривычную философию. Стоит ли переходить на новую технологию, или продолжать пользоваться SQL, или лучше попробовать использовать оба решения вместе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хранение неструктурированных единственная ваша цель, можно сесть на два стула сразу -- используйте PostgreSQL. Это все еще традиционная SQL база данных, но с [недавних пор](http://blog.evtuhovich.ru/blog/2012/03/14/postgresql-json/) она нативно поддерживает работу с JSON, и следовательно относительно такую же гибкость как и NoSQL (но не стоит обманываться, в MongoDB и CouchDB все же возможности хранения и обработки неструктурированных данных лучше).

Сам я люблю и обожаю монгу, но в последнее время многие с горяча переезжают на нее, не имея представления что их ждет и потом разочаровываются как в самой монге, так и в NoSQL в целом.

(Да, и как сказал котик совмещать две разные базы реляционную и не реляционную не стоит в этом случае)

Comment: Почитал про pgSQL - действительно, очень удобная и юзабельная!
А есть ли у неё нативный ООП интерфейс на php для работы с **prepared statements** ака **mysqli** ?

Comment: относительно такую же гибкость? вы серьезно? :)

Comment: @timophey увы, с php не работал, поэтому тут не подскажу
@AlexWindHope, трудно быть вангой, но я сильно подозреваю, что в контексте задач tymophey разница будет не сильно заметна

Comment: Может быть, действительно, говорить о вакуумных проблемах и задачах занятие неблагодарное :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я побуду адвокатом дьявола (увы, к ответу ниже не могу еще оставить комментарий, поэтому пишу здесь): http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com/

Comment: @om-nom-nom - я видел это видео :)

Answer (score 1):

некоторые +ы mongodb:

- свободная структура данных, которая, в большинстве случаев, лишает нас join'ов и не требует sql ужаса типа alter table
- высокая производительность, в первую очередь, по причине хранения данных в документах, а не в таблицах, что лишает нас join'ов, локов и т.д.
- очень удобная в вопросах масштабирования, которое практически не требует изменений вашего кода. В этом вопросе, у sql субд дела особенно печальны.
- отлично подходит на роль real time бд
- не совсем плюс самой БД, но все-же - на мой взгляд - отличная документация

В любом случае, в абсолютном большинстве случаев, когда вы пишите приложение, вы работаете с объектами, а не с таблицами, вашу логику не интересует реляционная алгебра и sql запросы, вам, чаще всего, просто нужны те или иные объекты (данные), но вы, в случае использования sql бд, вынуждены с ними мирится, а это, в свою очередь, сказывается не только на времени, красоте реализации, объеме кода, нервах и силах, но и на производительности.

Если вам это надоело, то вы, безусловно, должны попробовать mongo, либо ей подобную БД, в любом случае, от такого опыта вы только выиграете. Если что - всегда можно вернутся к "старому доброму" sql'ю.

Стоит заметить - в mongodb like бд не стоит хранить особо важные данные типа денежных счетов, для этого намного лучше подходит sql( либо, например, redis ). Но, даже в этом случае, никто вам не мешает хранить счета в sql, а все остальное в mongo.

###### т.к. для некоторых довольно важный фактор - [список некоторых проектов которые используют mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments)

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL - это вообще не база, а класс хранилищ данных, клоторые не относятся к традиционным SQL базам данных. Так, что из предложенных тобой вариантов остается только два: SQLite и MongoDb.

SQLite - это встраиваемое SQL решение, основанное на файлах. Если на пальцах - это апи доступа к данным, которые хранятся в локальных файлах посредством SQL синтаксиса, т.е. мало чем отличается от классических fread/fwrite и имеет те же недостатки, что и хранение данных на файлах.

ну что, теперь остается MongoDb - это система хранения данных, основанная на принципе хранении документов в BSON(Binary JSON) формате. 
Достоинства:

- имеет распределенный доступ к данным, расположенных на нескольких серверах
- возможно параллельное извлечение данных MapReduce
- более быстрое извлечение простых структур данных
- может хранить неструктурную информацию

Недостатки:

- менее чем более стабильна, не рекомендовано использовать в биллинге
- требовательна к ресурсам - память и место на диске
- Лочится вся коллекция, если используется внутренние функции которые работают с данными данной коллекции (аналог хранимых процедур). аналог творится то, что и с MyISAM.
- проблемы с решардингом

что использовать во многом зависит от задачи и имеющихся для ее решения ресурсов:
где-то лучше использовать MongoDb, где-то redis, где-то Reak или Cassandra.

А для этого надо познакомиться с ними со всеми поближе... Почитать блоги, развернуть на дев сервере, покрутить настройки и прочие ручечки.
Не реализовав на них ни одного проекта, нельзя говорить о достоинствах и недостатках.

В одном реализованном мною проекте, при использовании MongoDB, запихнулии ее на виртуалку, дали 1Гб и 2 ядра с возможностью перспективы роста проекта... Но, набрав какое-то кол-во пользователей, где-то более миллиона, MongoDb начала притормаживать из-за нехватки ресурсов... А выделенного сервера для нее так и не выдали, сказав, что проект сделан неправильно и тормозит... так что надо осознавать риски связанные с железом и используемым на нем софтом